# Form Customization without VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

We are rebuilding an asset database with Access 2013. We have 1 table with a Primary Key (Serial number of asset), and 22 other fields. We're designing a form to be used with the table so that we are not manually editing the table. The 'Status:' field explained later does not exist in the table; it is a user friendly way to show if the record exists or not.

The end goal is to have a form that will two cases. A user will enter a PK and hit the tab key. Then:

- If the PK exists, it will pull the info from the other 22 fields and put them into the fields on the form (1:1) and update 'Status:' to 'Existing'.
- If the PK does not exist, it will change the 'Status:' to 'New' and make all of the fields blank.

Most of the fields on the form will be Combo boxes. There will be a couple text fields and 1 date/time field.

Once a user is done with the form and has made any necessary changes, there will be a 'Save' button at the bottom that will write whatever is in the forms to the row indicated by the PK.

I have found partial solutions with the LostFocus() event in Access 2013 on the PK field of the form. I have little experience with MS Access, moderate experience with DBA, and no experience with VBA programming. I'm sure this solution can be done, my question is: can it be solved in a way other than hard coding the solutions? I also looked around for form building, but I couldn't find anything that worked how we need it so if there is a tool that can accomplish this, that is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a form that contains a [subform](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-HA101872705.aspx).  Basically, you would design a form that has your PK input box and a subform.  When the user hits tab (or a "Search" button), a query would run to search the table and display that record in the subform, or you could insert a new record if not.  You may need to use a few queries and macros to link it all together, but it can be done code-free.